# import 50GB mysql dump file

Tags: mysql, database, import, query-performance

I have started to work on a company that dump a huge database every day.
The file compressed is around 4GB, but I tried to uncompress it once and we are talking about over 50GB of file.

Now, I am trying to create a slave and in order to do that, I need to import the latest data.

I have never tried to import such huge file, and browsing around, I found the 'pv' command that shows me the progress bar.

The command I am running is:

```
pv database.sql.gz | gunzip | mysql -u root -p
```

The process start and it seems to be fairly fast at first, but then it starts to slow done until it reaches the [0KB/s]

I tried once and it took over 15 hours.
Is this normal? can somebody tell me if there is a better way (faster way perhaps) of doing it?

Thanks,

Comment: I guess you need to gunzip the file first. Can't remind any workaround. The thing is, compressed it's only 4GB, uncompressed it's over 50GB. So there's a lot of work to do when uncompressing.. imho, 15 hours sounds normal for a file compressed to ~8% in this memory-size

Comment: When importing a large sql file, progressive slowdown usually means the cost of inserting each new row into a table is proportional to the number of rows already inserted (classic `O(n-squared)` performance). If you can post the definition of the largest table, and a few rows of the insert, we may be able to give you advice.

Comment: Also, in a large gzipped file, especially a sql file, the compression ratio improves as the file grows longer. So late in the compressed file the number of bytes processed as input to `gunzip` becomes smaller for the same number of output bytes. That too can make `pv` think your process is slowing down.

Comment: @MatthiasBurger for what it's worth the overhead of gunzip is usually *less* than the overhead of reading the uncompressed file from a file system. Counterintuitive but true.

Answer (score 0):

Loading a table does *not* slow down.  Building an index *may* slow down.

Do not gunzip first; the I/O to write and reread the 50GB file will consume any savings you may think you will get.

12:1 compression ratio is very high.  Sounds like you have some inefficiencies in the datatypes.  Typical text compresses only 3:1.  Numbers (eg, `BIGINT` storing usually single-digit values: 4:1).  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; maybe you have `CHAR(999)` holding empty strings?

Is the dump `mysqldump`?  Does it include disabling and re-enabling the indexes?

Are you using UUIDs? (They are terribly inefficient to index.)